How to render a 3d model in a bitmap?
Is there any way in Android to render a 3D model in a Bitmap?
Here's what I wanna achieve:

load a 3D model;
transform that 3D model (rotation and/or scale);
set a light source (if possible), and;
render the result in a Bitmap.

I tried using the Google's Filament lib, but I couldn't achieve it properly. I didn't manage to get the bitmap from the TextureView without attaching it to the screen.
Is there any way to do it?

Looks like you want to do some offscreen rendering.
Here's one possible workflow:

Create an OpenGL texture, use it to create a SurfaceTexture and use the latter to create a Surface that Filament will render to.

Use OpenGL ES to render a textured rectangle sampled from the external texture (it should have type samplerExternalOES in the shader program) to a Framebuffer.

Read the pixels from the Framebuffer into a ByteBuffer and copy them into a Bitmap.


